# How can i import angular-2-local-storage in my angular 2 app (angular-cli)

Tags: angular, typescript, node-modules

How can I import `angular-2-local-storage` in my angular 2 app, I am using the angular-cli generator.
Floder stucture

[image]

`angular-2-local-storage` in node_module folder. I want to use it in my component. I am tryed this code

```
import { LocalStorageService } from '../../../node_modules/angular-2-local-storage';

constructor(
        private localStorageService: LocalStorageService
    ) { }
```

But getting this error

[image]

Comment: Why do you need a library for localstorage while the native code is only 1 line to get and set the data?

Answer (score 0):

For starters [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/) is a fanatic library if that is the route you are looking to go.  It supports typescript and if you are using the angular-cli and npm it is extremely easy to set up.

[DefinitelyType](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) is a collection of type script definition files that can be added to the project to provide strong typings for external libraries that may otherwise prove to be challenging to build in.

Once added, the angular cli will automatically included the dependencies in your project.  (Located in npm_modules with an @prefix) To use these libraries all just import a reference and you are basically good to go.  In some ways they can be used that same way as an angular 2 library.

Route 2 is also fairly simple for local storage, below is a snippet from a sandbox app.  This makes use of the localStorage in a service.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  private loggedIn = false;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.loggedIn = !!localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
  }

  login(email, password) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    let self = this;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      if (email === 'test@test.com' && password === 'test') {
        localStorage.setItem('auth_token', 'xyz');
        self.loggedIn = true;
        resolve(true);
      } else {
        resolve(false);
      }
    });
  }

  setPassword(password) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    let self = this;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      resolve(true);
    });
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('auth_token');
    this.loggedIn = false;
  }

  isLoggedIn() {
    return this.loggedIn;
  }
}
```